# Implementing continuous phase/Arg function

Tags: functions, signal-processing

In MATLAB there's a function called `phase` that is just like our `Listable` friend `Arg`, but that, when evaluated with a list, it tries to keep the result "continuous", allowing itself to return values outside the `[-Pi, Pi]` range. So, for example, sampling a complex exponential

```
vec = E^(I 2 π #/10) & /@ Range[100];
resMMA = Arg[vec] // N;
```

The red line is *Mathematica's* result with `Arg`, and the blue line is MATLAB's with `phase`

[image: enter image fdfdhere]

So, I want to implement a function that does a good job at allowing you to see phase properties such as "linearity", more easily, like `phase`, in Mathematica.
Ideally, it should also work on some symbolic functions and not only lists, but what's more important to me is for it to work as good as possible on lists.

My attempt at the "list version" is very simple, but seems to be working reasonably, and fast. I also tested it with a function that's positive and negative, like 
`vec2 = E^(I 2 Pi/16. #) Sinc[2 Pi #/20.] & /@ Range[100];`
Here's the code

```
phase = Compile[{{l, _Complex, 1}}, 
   FoldList[
    Function[{prev, new}, # + Round[prev - #, 2 Pi] &@Arg@new], 
    Arg@First@l, Rest@l], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];
```

Any improvements, would be appreciated. For example, it would probably be better if it could look at more than just the nearest neighbouring point, to be more robust to an occasional noise. I'd also appreciate ideas on how to achieve something analogous for a continuous well-behaved, not-created-by-mathematicians-just-to-prove-people-wrong symbolic function?

Comment: Indeed, very useful. I wonder how to implement similar thing for `Plot3D`. It'd be needed for example when solving a Schrodinger equation and plotting `Arg` of wave-function versus time and space.

Comment: For completeness, here is a straightforward *Mathematica* translation of the code used within MATLAB: `phase[vec_?VectorQ] := Module[{n = Length[vec], ph = Arg[vec], df}, df = Differences[ph]; Do[ph -= 2 Pi Sign[df[[k]]] PadRight[ConstantArray[0, k], n, 1], {k, Flatten[Position[Abs[df], _?(# > Pi &)]]}]; ph]`

Comment: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1998/May/msg00107.html

Answer (score 34):

For a continuous function you could do something like this:

```
SetAttributes[argPlot, HoldAll];
Options[argPlot] = Options[Plot];

argPlot[exp_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, opt : OptionsPattern[argPlot]] :=
 Module[{pts, pl},
  pl = Plot[Arg[exp], {x, x0, x1}, PlotRange -> All, 
    PlotPoints -> OptionValue[PlotPoints]];
  pts = SortBy[Cases[pl, Line[pts_] :> pts, Infinity], #[[1, 1]] &];
  pts = Reap[Fold[Module[{ptsn},
         ptsn = #2;
         ptsn[[All, 2]] -= Round[ptsn[[1, 2]] - #1, 2 Pi];
         Sow[ptsn];
         ptsn[[-1, 2]]] &, 0, pts];][[2, 1]];      
  ListLinePlot[Flatten[pts, 1], opt]]

argPlot[3 + 2 Exp[3 I a] + Exp[(1 - I a^2)], {a, -8, 8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Compared to an ordinary plot of the `Arg[3 + 2 Exp[3 I a] + Exp[(1 - I a^2)]]`

```
Plot[Arg[3 + 2 Exp[3 I a] + Exp[(1 - I a^2)]], {a, -8, 8}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice test function.

Comment: This doesn't work if the phase shift is around the origin, try:
 `argPlot[50/((s + 4) (s + 3) (s - 1)) + 1 /. 
   s -> \[ImaginaryJ] \[Omega] /. \[Omega] -> Tan[x], {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}]`

Answer (score 12):

This solution only considers direct differences, but is a bit shorter than the original (it doesn't contain compilation, though, and I didn't test the speed):

```
phase[l: {_?NumericQ ..}] :=
  Module[{args = Arg[l]},
         args+Prepend[2Pi Accumulate@-IntegerPart@Differences[args/Pi],0]]
```

The following solution definitely isn't the fastest, but generally should give the best possible result:

```
phase[l: {_?NumericQ ..}]:=
  With[{vars = Table[Unique[], {Length@l}]},
       Arg@l+2 Pi Accumulate@vars /.
         Last@NMinimize[{Total@Abs@Differences[Arg@l+2\[Pi] Accumulate@vars],
                         (Alternatives@@vars) \[Element] Integers &&
                         First@vars==0},
                        vars]]
```

Comment: Just a side note, the following is the compiled version of the first function: `Clear[phase];
phase = Compile[{{l, _Complex, 1}}, 
   Module[{args = Arg[l]}, 
    args + Prepend[2 Pi Accumulate@-IntegerPart@Differences[args/Pi], 0]], 
   RuntimeOptions -> "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False];
`

Answer (score 9):

We can transfer the phase function from Matlab to *Mathematica*:

```
phase[vec_List] := 
  Module[{phi, df, len, i},
    phi = Arg @ vec;
    df = Differences @ phi;
    len = Length @ phi;
    i = Flatten @ Position[df, x_ /; Abs[x] > 3.5];
    Do[phi = phi - (2 Pi*Sign[df[[j]]]*UnitStep[# - (j + 1)] & /@ Range[len]),
      {j, i}]; 
    phi]

data = Table[1/((3/2 Exp[I a])^4 - 1), {a, -8, 8, 0.01}];
data // phase // ListLinePlot
```

The output is

[image]

while

```
data // Arg // ListLinePlot
```

gives

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple answer for an ordinary list. The OP asked about:

```
vec = E^(I 2 \[Pi] #/10) & /@ Range[100];
resMMA = Arg[vec] // N;
```

Just a simple few functions is enough:

```
unwraped =   resMMA + Accumulate[2*Pi*Unitize[Threshold[Prepend[Differences[resMMA], 0.], 1]]];
ListLinePlot[{resMMA, unwraped}]
```

[image]

Sometimes you might need to subtract instead of add, if your saw-tooth is upside down.

Comment: I'd suggest to use `Threshold` instead of `Chop` because the former preserves packing of lists. And using `0.` instead of `0`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Thanks! I read about this, and agree. Changes made

Comment: This code doesn't work on [this dataset](https://pastebin.com/raw/QEJjLPRP) (which I import by `resMMA = Flatten@Import["/tmp/angles.csv"];`).