# Phase Unwrap List Of Points: Implementing continuous phase/Arg function for List of Points

Tags: functions, complex

I am looking for a function to unwrap phase of a list of points as done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782/implementing-continuous-phase-arg-function?rq=1) for the continuous case.

I have the Re/Im data as my input and would like the unwrapped phase as the output.

Does anyone know how to do this in Mathematica?

Comment: So when you have e.g. `x^2` as real part and `Cos[x]` as imaginary part the something like [`Plot[Arg[x^2 + I Cos[x]], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o6V50.png)?

Comment: What did you try, and where did it fail?  If you can't be more specific I have to agree that this is a duplicate of the question you referenced.