# Phase unwrapping

Tags: list-manipulation

I am facing a problem in unwrapping a phase.
I have a data set presented by $a_i$, where $i$ varies from $1$ to $N$. I need it as follows:

- If $\mathrm{abs}(a_{i+1} - a_i) > 3$, add $6 k \,$ to $a_{i+1}$, otherwise return $a_{i+1}$. If $a_{i+1} > a_i$ for the first time, $k = -1$, otherwise $k = 1$.
- For every time $\mathrm{abs}(a_{i+1} - a_i) > 3$ and $a_{i+1} > a_i$, $k \to k + 1$ otherwise $k \to k - 1$.

  For example, the first time $\mathrm{abs}(a_{i+1} - a_i) > 3$, add $6$ if $a_{i+1} > a_i$.  For the second time $\mathrm{abs}(a_{i+1} - a_i) > 3$, add $12$ if $a_{i+1} > a_i$.  And for third time, if $a_{i+1} < a_i$, add $6$ not $18$.

So, can anyone please help me to write the code in *Mathematica* for the above logic. I am getting stuck. And thank you in adv. for the help.

Comment: 1. Is this question about software _Mathematica_? 2. If the answer to the first problem is yes, then please illustrate your problem with a specific example, currently your question is not clear. 3. What have you tried so far?

Comment: "unwrapping a phase" - have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129882)?

Comment: Related: [PhaseUnwrap](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PhaseUnwrap)

Answer (score 6):

```
a = {1.1, 1.3, 7.5, 1.4, 13.2};

FoldList[Plus, a[[1]], Mod[Differences[a], 6, -3]]

(*    {1.1, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.2}    *)
```

`If` and `For` are not ideal; better do list processing.