# Detrending or removing linear trend from 2D data

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, fitting, interpolation, detrend

I have some data that when plotted I get an inclined graph, as described:

```
data = Import["p02q.dat", "Table"];

xdata = data[[All, 1]];
ydata = data[[All, 2]];

dataplot = Transpose[{xdata, ydata}];

plot2q = ListLinePlot[ dataplot, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, 
  ImageSize -> 800, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> Automatic, 
  InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, 2}]
```

[image]

My intention is to get a leveled graph out of this one, like the one bellow:
[image]

Could anyone suggest how to solve this, please?
Data file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0j6A5Qw3fzvT6Tae7CVFv4MLmfpRxY5/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Find a linear best fit, use this to define an angle to the x-axis, generate a rotation matrix, and apply that to your data

Comment: This looks like a phase unwrap problem. [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5782/12558) may help.

Comment: Find the best-fit linear function, $f(t)$, then subtract that from the data. (Don't rotate! What a mess! It means you'll have a non-function.)

Comment: Thank you! @David

Comment: Thank you. @b3m2a1

Comment: Thank you @Hugh

Answer (score 3):

Removing linear trend, as suggested in comments, is almost a one-liner (check out, `Fit`, `FindFit`, `LinearModelFit`):

```
data=Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/aWYk1Jba"];
lm=LinearModelFit[data,x,x];
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{data[[All,1]],lm["FitResiduals"]}],
PlotLabel->lm["BestFit"],PlotTheme->"Detailed"]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Vitaliy.

Answer (score 1):

I different version of the workflow from [Vitaliy's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/237029/34008) using both Quantile Regression and Least Squares fits. Note that the de-trending results are slightly different.

Get the [QRMon](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m) package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/MonadicProgramming/MonadicQuantileRegression.m"]
```

Get data:

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/aWYk1Jba"];
```

Construct a [QRMon](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2018/08/01/a-monad-for-quantile-regression-workflows/) workflow with data summarization, Quantile Regression and Least Squares fitting, and error plots:

```
qrObj = 
   QRMonUnit[data]⟹
    QRMonEchoDataSummary⟹
    QRMonQuantileRegression[1, 0.5, InterpolationOrder -> 1, Method -> {LinearProgramming, Method -> "InteriorPoint"}]⟹
    QRMonFit[{1, x}]⟹
    QRMonPlot⟹
    QRMonErrorPlots["RelativeErrors" -> False, PlotRange -> {-0.06, 0.16}];
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Get the regression functions:

```
aFuncs = qrObj⟹QRMonTakeRegressionFunctions;
Map[Simplify[#[x]] &, aFuncs]
```

[image]

Get the errors, i.e., the signal de-trendings:

```
aErrors = qrObj⟹QRMonErrors["RelativeErrors" -> False]⟹QRMonTakeValue;
```

```
ListLinePlot /@ aErrors
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, Anton.

Comment: @Florin Welcome, good luck!