# Does anyone have a Mathematica implementation of the standard $\arg\zeta(s)$ function required to evaluate $S(T)$?

Tags: special-functions, complex, number-theory

This question is related to my question [Is there an elegant exact formula for the zeta zero counting function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037391) on Math StackExchange.

---

**Question**: Does anyone have a Mathematica implementation of the standard $\arg\zeta(s)$ function required to evaluate the function $S(T)=\frac{\Im\left(\log\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)\right)}{\pi}=\frac{\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)}{\pi}$?

---

I believe Mathematica truncates $\arg\zeta(s)$ to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ whereas evaluation of $S(T)$ requires an analytic continuation of $\arg\zeta(s)$.

---

The answer posted to my question on Math StackExchange implies the analytic continuation of $\arg\zeta(s)$ is derived from the analytic continuation of $\log\zeta(s)$ and the relationship $\arg\zeta(s)=\Im(\log\zeta(s))$. The reason I formulated this question in terms of $\arg\zeta(s)$ instead of $\log\zeta(s)$ is because Mathematica simplifies $\Im(\log\zeta(s))$ to $\arg\zeta(s)$ which initially led to me to believe $\Im(\log\zeta(s))$ is derived from $\arg\zeta(s)$.

---

The fact that Mathematica does not properly evaluate $\log\zeta(s)$ and $\arg\zeta(s)$ is a bit upsetting and disturbing to me. This also seems to imply Mathematica may not be properly evaluating many of the functions related to $\zeta(s)$ such as those listed at [Zeta Functions & Polylogarithms](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ZetaFunctionsAndPolylogarithms.html). I've been evaluating many of these functions related to $\zeta(s)$ for about $4\frac{1}{2}$ years now and only recently became aware Mathematica is not evaluating all of these functions correctly.

---

Assuming the definitions of $N(T)$ and $N_0(T)$ in formulas (1) and (2) below, I've been told $N_0(T)=N(T)\,\forall\,T\ne\Im(\rho)$. This implies one can get a pretty good idea of what $\arg\zeta(s)$ looks like when evaluated along the critical line in the upper half-plane by evaluating formula (3) below.

---

**(1)** $\quad N(T)=\sum\limits_{0<\Im(\rho)\le T} 1$

**(2)** $\quad N_0(T)=1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\arg\left(\zeta\left(\frac12+i\,T\right)\right)}{\pi})$

$\qquad\qquad\quad\ =1+\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+\frac{\Im\left(\log\zeta\left(\frac12+i\,T\right)\right)}{\pi}$

**(3)** $\quad\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)=\pi\left(N(T)-\left(\frac{\vartheta(T)}{\pi}+1\right)\right),\quad T\ge 0\land T\ne\Im(\rho)$

---

Figure (1) below illustrates the Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ in orange overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ in blue in the interval $0<T<52$. The two dashed horizontal reference lines are at $\pm \pi$. Note the two evaluations are pretty much exactly the same in this interval except where $T=\Im(\rho)$ which I believe is because Mathematica does not truncate $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ in this interval.

---

[image: Figure (1)]

**Figure (1)**: Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ (orange) overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ (blue)

---

Figure (2) below illustrates the Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ in orange overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ in blue near Gram point $g_{126}$ and $\Im\left(\rho_{127}\right)$ where Gram's law is violated. The two dashed horizontal reference lines are at $\pm \pi$. Note Mathematica truncates $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ which is apparently inconsistent with the analytic continuation of $\log\zeta(s)$ and $\arg\zeta(s)=\Im(\log\zeta(s))$. The orange and red dots represent the discrete evaluation points $(g_{126},\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I $g_{126}$])}$ and $\left(\Im\left(\rho_{127}\right),\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,\Im\left(\rho_{127}\right)\right)\right)$ respectively.

---

[image: Figure (2)]

**Figure (2)**: Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ (orange) overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ (blue)

---

Figure (3) below illustrates the Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ in orange overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ in blue near Gram point $g_{6707}$, $\Im(\rho_{6709})$, and $\Im(\rho_{6710})$ where [Lehmer's Phenomenon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersPhenomenon.html) is exhibited. The two dashed horizontal reference lines are at $\pm \pi$. Note Mathematica once again truncates $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ to the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. The orange dot represents the discrete evaluation point $(g_{6707},\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I $g_{6707}$])}$ and the two red dots represent the evaluation points $\left(\Im\left(\rho_{6709}\right),\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,\Im\left(\rho_{6709}\right)\right)\right)$ and $\left(\Im\left(\rho_{6710}\right),\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,\Im\left(\rho_{6710}\right)\right)\right)$.

---

[image: Figure (3)]

**Figure (3)**: Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[1/2+I T]}$ (orange) overlaid on formula (3) for $\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)$ (blue)

Comment: What is arg supposed to return when $\zeta(s)=0$? I'm unsure what "an analytic continuation of $\arg\zeta(s)$" is exactly. Arg is not a complex-analytic function. I'd guess that you want a smooth function $\Bbb R\rightarrow R$ that maps $T \mapsto \arg\zeta\left({1\over2}+T\right)$. I still think there has to be a discontinuity when the path of ${1\over2}+T$ passes through zero. I also think that if you want an arg that is not path-dependent, a simply connected domain for $s$ that excludes zeros needs to be specified. Am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I believe the answer posted to my question on Math StackExchange (see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4037551) provides more insight.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5782)

Comment: A bit of caution seems in order due to [Lehmer's phenomenon](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LehmersPhenomenon.html) of closely-spaced pairs of ζ-zeros, which means that the phase jumps across the zeros are not always of the same sign. For an example, have a look at `Plot[Arg[Zeta[1/2+I*t]]/Pi, {t, 7005, 7005.15}]` close to the ζ-zero pair `ZetaZero[6709] == 0.5 + 7005.06*I` and `ZetaZero[6710] == 0.5 + 7005.1*I`: complementary phase jumps cause trouble.

Comment: @Roman The standard definition of $\arg\zeta(s)$ used in the evaluation of the function $S(T)=\frac{\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)}{\pi}$ is not the same as the Mathematica evaluation of "Arg[Zeta[s]]" which is my motivation for this question.

Comment: Please include the definition of the standard argument to which you refer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 The best I can do is refer you to the answer posted to my question on Math StackExchange which I already did in a comment above. The reason for my question here is I'm seeking an implementation of the standard definition of $\arg\zeta(s)$ in the context of the evaluation of $S(T)=\frac{\arg\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}+i\,T\right)}{\pi}$, but a formula that can practically be evaluated would also be useful since I could then define my own implementation. I don't understand analytic continuation well enough to derive the formula for $\arg\zeta(s)$.

Comment: Why not just add it up manually starting from t=0.  I see no other way to compute the analytic continuation of the argument other than this way.  At least try it for say t=0 to 50 and then compare the number of zeros in the region.  If Re<0 and Im changes from neg to pos, change is -(Pi-Arg), If Re<0 and Im changes from pos to neg, change is -(Arg+Pi).  I think this is correct.  Would need to just expreiment and confirm the change is continuous.

Comment: Here's a Wolfram demo showing how to compute the analytic continuation of the "Arg" function.  This is the "arg" function:  https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheArgumentPrincipleInComplexAnalysis/

Comment: @MichaelE2 I updated the question above in an attempt to clarify the analytic continuation.

Comment: @Roman Figure (3) in my updated question above illustrates what the analytic continuation of $\arg\zeta(s)$ should look like versus the Mathematica evaluation of $\text{Arg[Zeta[s]]}$ when both are evaluated along the critical line near Gram point $g_{6707}$, $\Im(\rho_{6709})$, and $\Im(\rho_{6710})$ where Lehmer's phenomen is exhibited.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now. I thought I had a solution yesterday; but it fails in a couple of rare places, and I couldn't figure out why.

Comment: @Dominic I updated the question in an attempt to clarify the analytic continuation.

Comment: @StevenClark Thanks for the clarifications. It seems quite straightforward to do a phase correction in line with what J.M. suggests, but there will always be cases where it fails due to Lehmer's issues if you go high enough in $T$. I feel totally out of my math skill depth here, sorry.